# Postgres taking 3h to DELETE CASCADE

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, delete, cascade

I have a Postgresql 9.3 with a "mother" table containing items, and a number of "child" tables containing parts of different kinds (e.g. item "AAA" is composed of 1000 parts "P1", 800 parts "P2", 40 parts "P3", ...).

The `items` table contains ~500k rows, and each row references between 10 and 10000 rows on each `part` table, meaning each `part` table can contain several million rows.

Each table has a `_id_` primary key, and each "child" table has a foreign key pointing to `item._id_` (with an index) and UPDATE/DELETE CASCADE so that all parts are deleted when an item is deleted. Some parts reference each other as well.

`SELECT` on `item` and `parts` tables is quite fast (`SELECT * FROM p1 WHERE item_id=?` <1000 ms) but `DELETE` is awfully slow: it took a full 24h just to `DELETE FROM item WHERE _id_=?`.

I tried to delete sequentially from each `parts` with `DELETE FROM p1 WHERE item_id=?`: the first deletion took 3h but the next ones took a few ms only... Can it be some inefficient cache-fetching? In case statistics were a problem, I ran a `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the whole database (which completed in a couple hours) but deletion still is painfully slow. Items are added at a pace of 10/h so I will eventually run out of disk space in the near future (~100 GB left now).

I ran `EXPLAIN ANALYZE DELETE FROM item WHERE _id_=?`:

```
Delete on "item"  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=10375838.942..10375838.942 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using "item_pkey" on "item"  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.043..0.054 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ("_id_" = 29878)
Total runtime: 10375838.996 ms"
```

I'm don't know much about those costs and their meaning; I just see it is using the index, but I can't explain why it takes so long. The deleted items are the old ones, barely accessed (if at all), so I could understand cache miss.

Is there any parameter to tune to speed it up? I can also wait for maintenance time to do some things like dropping indexes, deleting rows, rebuilding indexes, as we can lock down the database (but then, what to do?), but I would prefer to be able to do it live, if possible. If I have to choose, the database should be optimized for fast INSERT and SELECT over fast DELETE.

Here is an excerpt from the table definitions:

```
TABLE item(
    _id_ serial,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT item_pkey PRIMAY KEY (_id_)
)

TABLE p1(
    _id_ serial,
    item_id integer,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT p1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (_id_)
    CONSTRAINT fk_item FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
        REFERENCES item(_id_)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
CREATE INDEX idx_p1_item ON p1 USING btree(item_id)

TABLE p2(
    _id_ serial,
    item_id integer,
    p1_id integer,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT p2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (_id_)
    CONSTRAINT fk_item FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
        REFERENCES item(_id_)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
    CONSTRAINT fk_p1 FOREIGN KEY (p1_id)
        REFERENCES p1(_id_)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
CREATE INDEX idx_p2_item ON p2 USING btree(item_id)
CREATE INDEX idx_p2_p1 ON p2 USING btree(p1_id)
```

Comment: Can you run `explain (analyze, verbose)` please, then add the output to your question. That should include the time the delete trigger took for the cascading delete

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, I ran it a couple hours after your post, it is still running (showing >48 000 000 ms so far). Please be patient...

Comment: Did you check if it's maybe just waiting for a lock?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It could be something like that, as my auto-clean process was still running a `DELETE FROM item` in the background. So I stopped and restarted it. I went to "Server status" in pgAdmin and I see around 80 "RowExclusiveLock" taken by the query. It is shown as "active" and not blocked by anything. How do I check locking status? (sorry for the n00b question)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the query finally ended after 28h30, and it showed a foreign key loop that I will detail in an upcoming answer. After deleting those constraints (that didn't really need to be there in the first place), it now deletes 15 rows/s. Many thanks for the `(analyze, verbose)` tip! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Danke schön to @a_horse_with_no_name for pointing `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE` that shed light on a foreign key loop in my definitions.

I need to explain more about the tables:

- An `item` is composed of parts `p1`, `p2`, ... (12 or 13 types) and of "meta parts" `meta_p1` that are groups of several parts `p1`
- A `device` is like an `item` (it is also composed of parts and meta part 1) but with different columns.

Which means we have a graph like this (mind the ASCII-art ;))

```
 DEVICE       ITEM
(1)(1)       (1)(1)
 |   \       /   |
  \  (n)   (n)  /
   \  META_P1  /
    \   (1)   /
     \   |   /
     (n)(n)(n)
         P1
```

(I might have reversed `(1)` and `(n)`, I mean "**(1)** item has **(n)** meta_p1").

Whenever an `item` is deleted, I want all parts `p1`, `p2`, ... and `meta_p1` to be deleted as well. Same when deleting a `meta_p1`: all `p1` "contained" in the meta part were supposed to be deleted (which is a logic flaw, as an instance of `p1` can also exist outside of `meta_p1`). It meant that there would be a kind of n^2 search because of that loop (delete item => delete p1 and meta_p1 but delete meta_p1 also means delete p1), as shown on the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE` results:

```
Delete on public.item  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.100..0.100 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using "item_pkey" on public.item  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.040..0.041 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: ctid
        Index Cond: (item._id_ = 29919)
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24686 for constraint fk_item on item: time=0.116 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24719 for constraint fk_item on item: time=0.232 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24747 for constraint fk_item on item: time=33.225 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24784 for constraint fk_item on item: time=50.434 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24817 for constraint fk_item on item: time=0.351 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24840 for constraint fk_item on item: time=0.333 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24863 for constraint fk_item on item: time=0.278 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24886 for constraint fk_item on item: time=0.269 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24909 for constraint fk_item on item: time=0.318 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24932 for constraint fk_item on item: time=0.142 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24950 for constraint fk_item on item: time=16.547 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24977 for constraint fk_item on item: time=48.029 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_25003 for constraint fk_item on item: time=0.182 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24769 for constraint fk_p1 on meta_p1: time=1285.033 calls=53
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_24789 for constraint fk_dev on meta_p1: time=102571647.818 calls=53
Total runtime: 102573083.569 ms
```

The `constraint fk_item on item` are one for each `p*` table, and the last two lines show the loop (though I don't understand what `fk_dev` is doing here as I'm not considering "devices" but "parts").

(Table definitions were not included for brevity).

Comment: The usual reason for such slow RI Triggers are missing indexes on the FK column (the referencing the table being deleted)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have indexes on all foreign keys, though I now recall I dropped those on `device` because of very low disk space (and no devices on that particular system). It explains the huge time on `fk_dev`. Always nice to have an explanation :)
What is an "RI trigger"?

Comment: An "RI Trigger" is the trigger that is used to enforce foreign keys during DML statements. When deleting rows from a table that is referenced by other tables, the RI trigger checks if nothing else references the row to be deleted. It does that by using a SQL query using the foreign key column in the WHERE clause. If the FK columns aren't indexed, that SQL statement is going to run a Seq Scan for each and every deleted row.